# How to make a dice logic in UPBGE 0.3?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm trying to restore a dice created in the Blender Game Engine so it can work in UPBGE 0.3.

The last time I saved this file was in Blender 2.79b.

I tried to purge the elements but there is some problems with the inherited textures. The path to the textures and their dependencies looks to be broken (probably due this file being made on Blender 2.49b or even older BGE versions. However the dice still works in Blender 2.79b.

Maybe it's possible to simplify and use text instead of textures?

Any help is appreciated.

The links bellow hosts the same .blend file "Dice279bCPACK.blend" (Last save in Blender 2.79b) in two different services:

1. Blend-Exchange: [image]
2. Google drive:
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YiF8zEVRIIQ5woRbDcr8p0v-xQ4vgPYC/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Blender doesn't have a game engine nowadays. Try asking in one of the UPBGE forums here: https://upbge.org/#/community.

Comment: Hi, chic.. sorry..  BGE is no longer part of the Blender release, so is no longer on-topic on Blender SE.  @JohnEason has pointed you to the right place to ask.

Comment: Hi Guys!

The UPBGE community link is redirecting to here.

UPGE 0.3 is Blender 3.0 plus the Game Engine.

Comment: Hi, @chicOritz.. (really want to help, here)... To answer your problem, would we have to install UPBGE? This forum is about vanilla Blender and its shipped add-ons. If we can't answer from a standard install, that's very tricky, on this SE.  I'm not sure UPBGE should be directing here, I'm thinking of contacting them, but am open to correction.  Just in case I've got the wrong end of the stick,  what are your thoughts, before we do?

Comment: @chicOrtiz After discussion with other mods.. glad to say, we are accepting UPBGE questions. I'm  sorry for any inconvenience my closure has caused.  and  I hope you will find users here with enough experience to help you. If more UPGE users are being sent here, then chances will improve, over time.

Comment: Hello Robin Betts! Thank you so much for opening this question again! This gesture means a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a temporary solution using just text instead of texture (Saved in UPBGE 0.30):

DiceTextUPBGE030A.blend Links:

Blend-Exchange: [image]

Google drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RHCV5PhJdmVotNoaZzicxYz1s-0JYruk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution! However, an answer should never be given only with a link to an external file and without further detailed explanation. In the long run, such an answer has no value for this platform because external links to proprietary clouds can be lost. Please try to show the solution in detail and always use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share a blend file. Thank you for your understanding!